# Create simple scatter plot with Dimple

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dimple.js

Using [dimple.js](http://dimplejs.org/index.html), I'm trying to create a simple scatter plot. However, the only result I'm getting is a bar graph, and I'm not sure how to switch it to a scatter. My data looks like this;

```
var data = [
    {"Month":new Date(1942, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), "Workers":0},
    {"Month":new Date(1942, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), "Workers":667}
    ...
]
```

I then create the graph like this

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg("body", 800, 600);
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Month");
    x.addOrderRule("Date");
chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Workers");
chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
chart.draw();
```

I tried changing `x` to `chart.addMeasureAxis("x", "Month")`, but then the chart would not even  render. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render a scatter plot you need to change:

```
chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
```

to

```
chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bubble);
```

The different axes allow you to change between the different types of scatter plot.  With a category axis on x you will get equally spaced points which might look more suitable as a line chart (just change the above to `dimple.plot.line`).  Two measure axes will make for a more standard scatter plot, in which case you will probably want to pass a dimension to the first parameter of addSeries, otherwise all the data will be aggregated to a single point.  You can see all the basic types of scatter plot and how to create them in the [examples on the website](http://dimplejs.org/examples_index.html).